# Add additional xsd schemas with libXml2

Tags: libxml2

I have a xml and schema which I want to validate. I don't want schema to be stored in file, but in database location. I use `xmlSchemaNewMemParserCtxt` to parse the schema. The problem is that this schema references another schema for basic types: `<xs:include schemaLocation="CommonTypes.xsd"/>`, which libXml2 searches in the current working directory. Is there any way to supply these additional schemas in memory buffer?

Answer (score 0):

[xmlRegisterInputCallbacks](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlIO.html#xmlRegisterInputCallbacks) is what you're probably looking for.

The advantage, they let you construct some kind of a virtual I/O layer. The disadvantage, inputcallbacks are set globally (there is however [xmlPopInputCallbacks](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlIO.html#xmlPopInputCallbacks) and [xmlCleanupInputCallbacks](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlIO.html#xmlCleanupInputCallbacks)).

The code below (built upon code from [http://knol2share.blogspot.be](http://knol2share.blogspot.be/2009/05/validate-xml-against-xsd-in-c.html)) demonstrates the use of [xmlRegisterInputCallbacks](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlIO.html#xmlCleanupInputCallbacks).

All xml and xsd files are loaded from the file system, except when the URI contains "DataTypes.xsd" the schema is fetched from a string. (since schemaLocation is only a hint one could for example prefix schema's

"**test.xsd**": the main xml schema (please ignore the reference to peacelane.org, namespaces are from a hobby project, just occurred to me now www.peacelane.org might exist, apparently it does...)

```xml
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:tns="http://peacelane.org/ApplianceType/config/45/LIGHTING1/ARC" 
        xmlns:dt="http://peacelane.org/ApplianceType/config/45/DataTypes"
        targetNamespace="http://peacelane.org/ApplianceType/config/45/LIGHTING1/ARC"
        elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <import namespace="http://peacelane.org/ApplianceType/config/45/DataTypes" schemaLocation="DataTypes.xsd" />
    <complexType name="ConfigType">
        <sequence>
            <element name="housecode" type="dt:char" />
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
    <element name="Config" type="tns:ConfigType"/>
</schema>
```

"**test.xml**": a test xml to validate

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Config xmlns="http://peacelane.org/ApplianceType/config/45/LIGHTING1/ARC">
    <housecode>A</housecode>
</Config>
```

"**main.c**": the actual code (update the paths for "XMLFileName" and "XSDFileName")

```c
#define LIBXML_SCHEMAS_ENABLED
#include <libxml/xmlschemastypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static const char *databaseSchema =
        "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"
                "       <schema elementFormDefault=\"qualified\" xmlns:tns=\"http://peacelane.org/ApplianceType/config/45/DataTypes\"  targetNamespace=\"http://peacelane.org/ApplianceType/config/45/DataTypes\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">"
                "           <simpleType name=\"char\">"
                "               <restriction base=\"string\">"
                "                   <length value=\"1\" />"
                "               </restriction>"
                "           </simpleType>"
                "       </schema>";

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//-- SQL Callbacks (~ simulated db actions)
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
static void* sqlOpen(const char * URI) {
    return ((void *) databaseSchema );
}

static int sqlClose(void * context) {
    return (0);
}

static int sqlRead(void * context, char * buffer, int len) {
    const char* result= (const char *) context;
    int rlen = strlen(result);
    memcpy(buffer, result, rlen);
    return rlen +1;
}

static int sqlMatch(const char * URI) {
    if ((URI != NULL )&& (strstr(URI, "DataTypes.xsd") != NULL) )return 1;
    return 0;
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//-- File callbacks
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
static void* fileOpen(const char * URI) {
    if (URI == NULL )
        return (NULL );
    FILE* fh = fopen(URI, "rt");
    return ((void *) fh);
}

static int fileClose(void * context) {
    FILE* fh = (FILE*) context;
    if (fh != NULL )
        fclose(fh);
    return (0);
}

static int fileRead(void * context, char * buffer, int len) {
    FILE* fh = (FILE*) context;

    fseek(fh, 0L, SEEK_END);
    long flen = ftell(fh);
    rewind(fh);

    if (buffer != NULL )
        fread(buffer, flen, 1, fh);

    return flen + 1;
}

static int fileMatch(const char * URI) {
    if ((URI != NULL ))
        if (strstr(URI, "DataTypes.xsd") == NULL ) {
            return (1);
        }

    return (0);
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//-- Main
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    xmlDocPtr doc;
    xmlSchemaPtr schema = NULL;
    xmlSchemaParserCtxtPtr ctxt;
    char *XMLFileName =
            "/home/dogguts/Projects/libxml2tests/xsdparse/Debug/test.xml";
    char *XSDFileName =
            "/home/dogguts/Projects/libxml2tests/xsdparse/Debug/test.xsd";

    xmlLineNumbersDefault(1);

    if (xmlRegisterInputCallbacks(fileMatch, fileOpen, fileRead, fileClose)
            < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to register File handler\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (xmlRegisterInputCallbacks(sqlMatch, sqlOpen, sqlRead, sqlClose) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to register SQL handler\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    ctxt = xmlSchemaNewParserCtxt(XSDFileName);

    xmlSchemaSetParserErrors(ctxt, (xmlSchemaValidityErrorFunc) fprintf,
            (xmlSchemaValidityWarningFunc) fprintf, stderr);
    schema = xmlSchemaParse(ctxt);
    xmlSchemaFreeParserCtxt(ctxt);

    xmlSchemaDump(stdout, schema);

    doc = xmlReadFile(XMLFileName, NULL, 0);

    if (doc == NULL ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not parse %s\n", XMLFileName);
    } else {
        xmlSchemaValidCtxtPtr ctxt;
        int ret;

        ctxt = xmlSchemaNewValidCtxt(schema);
        xmlSchemaSetValidErrors(ctxt, (xmlSchemaValidityErrorFunc) fprintf,
                (xmlSchemaValidityWarningFunc) fprintf, stderr);
        ret = xmlSchemaValidateDoc(ctxt, doc);
        if (ret == 0) {
            printf("%s validates\n", XMLFileName);
        } else if (ret > 0) {
            printf("%s fails to validate\n", XMLFileName);
        } else {
            printf("%s validation generated an internal error\n", XMLFileName);
        }
        xmlSchemaFreeValidCtxt(ctxt);
        xmlFreeDoc(doc);
    }

    if (schema != NULL )
        xmlSchemaFree(schema);

    xmlSchemaCleanupTypes();
    xmlCleanupParser();
    xmlMemoryDump();

    return (0);
}
```

---

*Notice that, for brevity, the above code doesnt' perform any checks wether (file, memory,...) operations succeeded.*

Comment: I see this question dates from nov. 2012.  If by any chance you (or someone else) found a better/other solution, care to share it here?

Comment: Is `xmlSchemaCleanupTypes` multi-thread safe? `xmlCleanupParser()` is not, but the docu of `xmlSchemaCleanupTypes()` is rather brief and does not mention this aspect.

Answer (score 0):

This is a better example how to do it: io1.c
http://www.xmlsoft.org/examples/

It saves a lot of time when you can find what is good way to return value from Read function.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.